# Which machine learning algorithms to use for given Problem

Tags: machine-learning, regression, supervised-learning

I want to implement the ML on the menu in an ERP application, what i want is the menu order should change based on the user behaviour.

I have data in below format:

```
Sn Role   Time    MenuID
1  admin  1830    menu1
2. admin  1900    menu2.....
```

What I want is, based on current user role and time, ML should predict which MenuID to put first?

Should I treat it as supervised learning since it could be a labelled data and its regression problem because I expect the output as number(menu order)?

I read a lot of tutorials but I can't to decide where to start. I don't need any code, I just want a starting point.

Comment: I think this might be a decision tree problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use a basic regression approach where your input features would be the user role and the time, and the target variable you would be predicting would be the menu they are most likely on at that time (You'd need to convert all this categorical data into one-hot encoded data). Also, if you apply a softmax function to the outputs, then you could get the individual probabilities for each menu and then arrange them accordingly.